# Почему не работает делегирование?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю тему по учебнику. В нем есть пример, который работает в сэндбоксе. Я его скопировал и переделал под свои нужды.

```
let calc = document.querySelector(".calc");

calc.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.className === 'button') {
        console.log('Click!');
    }
});

<div class="calc">
    <div class="screen">
        <p class="screen__p">2344
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <button class="button back">&#8592;</button>
        <button class="button reset">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-wrap">
        <button class="button num7">7</button>
        <button class="button num8 pressed">8</button>
        <button class="button num9">9</button>
        <button class="button minus">-</button>
        <button class="button plus">+</button>
        <button class="button num4">4</button>
        <button class="button num5">5</button>
        <button class="button num6">6</button>
        <button class="button multiple">&times;</button>
        <button class="button divide">&divide;</button>
        <button class="button num1">1</button>
        <button class="button num2">2</button>
        <button class="button num3">3</button>
        <button class="button radical">&#8730;</button>
        <button class="button power">X<sup>y</sup></button>
    </div>
    <div class="block block3">
        <button class="button zero">0</button>
        <button class="button dot">.</button>
        <button class="button equally">=</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: не добавляйте код в виде изображения. В таком виде никто его не сможет проверить

Comment: Уберите пожалуйста скрин и вставьте вместо него код в специальный блок

Comment: Напишите `console.log(event.target.className)` перед `if` - сами поймете, надеюсь.

Answer (score 1):

`.className` возвращает строку со всеми классами `button zero` и т.д. Она не будет равна `button`, но в тоже время подстрока `button` будет в ней. Просто проверьте, есть ли слово `button` в строке с помощью `includes()`.

```js
const calc = document.querySelector(".calc");

calc.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.className == 'button') {
    console.log('Работает ===');
  }

  if (event.target.className.includes('button')) {
    console.log('Работает includes');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <button class="button class1">Нет</button>
  <button class="button class2">Нет</button>
  <button class="button">Да</button>
</div>
```

А еще лучше написать так: `event.target.classList.contains('button')`.

Ваш код:

```js
const calc = document.querySelector(".calc");

calc.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('button')) {
    console.log('Click!');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="screen">
    <p class="screen__p">2344
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <button class="button back">&#8592;</button>
    <button class="button reset">C</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-wrap">
    <button class="button num7">7</button>
    <button class="button num8 pressed">8</button>
    <button class="button num9">9</button>
    <button class="button minus">-</button>
    <button class="button plus">+</button>
    <button class="button num4">4</button>
    <button class="button num5">5</button>
    <button class="button num6">6</button>
    <button class="button multiple">&times;</button>
    <button class="button divide">&divide;</button>
    <button class="button num1">1</button>
    <button class="button num2">2</button>
    <button class="button num3">3</button>
    <button class="button radical">&#8730;</button>
    <button class="button power">X<sup>y</sup></button>
  </div>
  <div class="block block3">
    <button class="button zero">0</button>
    <button class="button dot">.</button>
    <button class="button equally">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все равно не работает, даже с копированием вашего кода. Редактор подчеркивает и пишет ошибку "Unresolved variable className"

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин, `className` это не переменная должна быть, а свойство объекта.

Comment: Не знаю, что я сделал, но код заработал. Редактор, кстати, все равно подчеркивает ClassName

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин Слева от ответа знак "галочка".